# Ion Auth returns 404 on all views

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404, ion-auth

Hey i'm new to CI and i guess i'm missing some fundemental understanding of CI and MVC in general.

I've copied all the [Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) files to their places, created all tables, created encryption key.

but when i tried to enter any view i get a 404.

Am i suppoused to write anything in my routes file? why could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i had this code in `routes.php` :

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Which of course means any call is being sent there, which dosen't exist.